# How to set title of the dialog in center horizontally in android

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

This is my code to show a custom dialog in android.

```
private void showCouponCodeDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoge_apply_coupon);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.apply_coupon);

    final ProgressBar progressBar =(ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    Button btnApplyCoupon = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnApplyCoupon);
    btnApplyCoupon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

How to set title of the dialog in center horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom style , set gravity as you want to the specific one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/PauseDialogTitle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="PauseDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
            <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        </style>
        <style name="DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Assign the style to dialog

```
Dialog pauseDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog);
```

do other stuff as normal

or set custom title manually

```
// Creating the AlertDialog with a custom xml layout (you can still use the default Android version)
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewname, null);
builder.setView(view);

TextView title = new TextView(this);
// You Can Customise your Title here 
title.setText("Custom Centered Title");
title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
title.setTextSize(20);

builder.setCustomTitle(title);
```